# How do the parameters in C++ Lambda expressions work?

Tags: c++, lambda

Take for example the following code:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5};
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int x, int y) {return x > y; });
```

This code sorts the vector in descending order, however I don't fully understand the mechanisms at play. The vector contains 5 elements, however the parameters only contain two variables -- int x and int y. I want to know how this lambda expression sorts every element in the vector when it only accepts two variables as parameters.

Comment: I think you're just confused how the [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function works. The 3rd parameter is the comparison function that the sort function uses to know whether an element is "less than" another one.

Comment: All the elements of the container are passed two by two to those 2 parameters of the lambda. Not just the first two elements. All of them.

Comment: Lambda expression doesn't sort the elements: `std:sort` does. To do this, `std::sort` needs to know whether a given element should precede or follow another given element in the sorted order - that's what it calls the lambda for.

Comment: digito_evo Yes this is exactly what I was asking I just didn't phrase it correctly. So it is passed two by two to the parameters of the lambda. So then my question is, does this lambda expression inside the sort function act as a bubble sort algorithm? Because it must pass over the values multiple times in order to achieve a sorted vector, just like in the bubble sort.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda function (`[](int x, int y) {return x > y; }`) in your sort function call is just like any other regular function without a name, that gets called "N" number of times based on number of input elements.

To understand more about that simply add few print statements in that lambda as shown below.

```
std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5};
    
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int a, int b) {
        std::cout << "a value : " << a <<std::endl;
        std::cout << "b value : " << b <<std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return a > b;
    });
```

Now the output is

```
a value : 2
b value : 1

a value : 3
b value : 2

a value : 4
b value : 3

a value : 5
b value : 4
```

So the lamda is called 4 times for the input five elements on my compiler.

Comment: So then my question is, does this lambda expression inside the sort function act as a bubble sort algorithm? Because it must pass over the values multiple times in order to achieve a sorted vector, just like in the bubble sort.

Comment: No. The lambda here is just a function to compare when two parameters are given. It is nothing to do with algorithm.

Comment: The standards expects the time complexity to be O(N log N). The implimentation of algorithm is left to different compilers. Refer https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(C%2B%2B).      Go to section complexity and implementations